# Regex in jQuery: numbers within brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Is it possible to get numbers within brackets from string with RegEx?
For example, I have selects with content like:

```
<select class="selectoption">
    <option value="1">no numbers</option>
    <option value="2">3 (+110.0 грн.)</option>
    <option value="3">Blabla (+95.5 грн.)</option>
</select>
```

I need to get only numbers, when user select option with brackets (110 or 95.5).

Now I have:

```
$('.selectoption').change(function() {
    if ( $("select option:selected").text().match(/\(.*\)/).length ){}
        alert (
            $("select option:selected").text().match(/\(.*\)/)
        );
    end
});
```

But it returns `(+110.0 грн.)` :(

Comment: `live` is deprecated. Just so you'll know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match returns array of char group which you defined in regexp.
You can use replace instead match

```
  $("select option:selected").text().replace(/^(.*)\([^\)\d]*(\d+\.\d+)[^\)\d]*\)$/, '$2')
```

Comment: Thanks... I'm not familiar with regex. It returns +110.0 грн., but I don't need + and ` грн.` :)

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
$('.selectoption').on('change', function () {
  var m = $(this).find(':selected').text().match(/\(.*?([\d.]+).*?\)/);
  console.log(
    m && m[1] || 'n/a'
  ); 
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ekanog/1/

Comment: +1, I'd post `/\(\D*(\d+?(?:\.\d+)?)\D*\)/` as an answer but your regex looks much more cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Should look something like that:

```
$('form').on('change', '.selectoption', function() {
    var content = $('option:selected', this).text(),
        matches = content.match(/\([^\d]*(\d+(\.\d*)?)/);
    if (matches.length) {
        alert(matches[1]);
    }
});
```

`form` being one of `.selectoption` parents, change the selector if it is uncorrect.

Incase you don't need delegation you can use:

```
$('.selectoption').on('change', function() {
```

As you did on your edit. It's works all the same :)

**[Example Code](http://jsfiddle.net/h4T2J/1/)**

Comment: Thanks! But one more thing... `(+100 грн.) => 100`, but `(+99.5 грн.) => 99` (without .5) :-[

Comment: That's what it does. Look at the code example I've added. (Unless you wanna keep the fraction?)

Comment: Fixed it to take fractions too.

Comment: Works now! Unfortunately, I can't accept more answers, but it's nice variant, thanks!